# In the phrase: "She swallowed her words", what literary device is being used?

Tags: american-english, rhetorical-devices, literary-device

Words can't be swallowed, so there has to be some literary device being used here. It's not a metaphor or simile because words are not being compared to anything, and it's not personification either since words are not doing any human actions. I can't think of any other literary device that's related to this.

Comment: Why isn't it a metaphor? It's comparing her actions to swallowing.

Comment: I think it could be considered one--a humerous one (at least in 1702).

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though this an **idiom**, a phrase with a non-literal meaning.

Lexico Dictionary describes it as "A group of words established by usage as having a meaning not deducible from those of the individual words (e.g., rain cats and dogs, see the light)".

Answer (score 0):

**paronomasia** (in the sense of a play on considering *words* as food and *swallowing* or *eating* them as a way of retracting something said)

> A play on words: PUN [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paronomasia)

> *Rhetoric*
> Wordplay based on words which sound alike; an instance of this, a pun. OED

> **Paronomasia** noun – **A humorous play on words**. Double entendre and paronomasia are semantically related in play on words topic.
> [thesaurus.plus](https://thesaurus.plus/related/double_entendre/paronomasia)

> Origin Late 16th century via Latin from Greek paronomasia, from para-
> ‘beside’ (expressing alteration) + onomasia ‘naming’ (from onomazein
> ‘to name’, from onoma ‘a name’). [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/paronomasia)

**swallow one's words**

> Take back what one said, as in If they win I'll have to swallow my
> words.
>
> George Farquhar used this **idiom** in The Inconstant (1702): “I have
> swallowed my words already; I have eaten them up.” For a synonym, see
> eat one's words. [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/swallow-one-s-words)

**eat one's words**

> Phrase. Retract what one has said, especially in a humiliated way. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/eat_one%27s_words)

---

> **witticism** *noun* joke, quip, witty remark ... *rare* **paronomasia**, equivoque, Atticism. [Maurice Waite; *Oxford Thesaurus of English*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Oxford_Thesaurus_of_English/CaCcAQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22eat%20one%27s%20words%22%20paronomasia&pg=PA976&printsec=frontcover)

> **Paronomasia: Definition and Examples**
> ...
> I used to be a tap dancer until I fell in the sink [thoughtco](https://www.thoughtco.com/paronomasia-word-play-1691572)
>
> "I have a mind to join a club and beat you over the head with it."
> (Groucho Marx)

Comment: Paronomasia usually refers to a pun, which is utilizing similarities between the sounds of words to create humorous or other effect. I don't really see that in "swallow one's words". Witticism works slightly better.

Comment: @turkey Isn't it also a play on words in that more than one meaning is suggested: words as food?

Comment: It does suggest that, but I don't believe a definition of word refers to food (correct me if I'm mistaken). Normally a pun involving meanings would use a word with two, already established and different meanings (like the bird duck and to duck under).

Comment: @turkey No, not a traditional pun. See the Paronomasia examples online that I've added. I believe these are similar plays on a word's meaning.